# Symfony - Voter always the same object received

Tags: security, symfony, symfony-security

I have implemented the following Voter

**Service definition**

```yml
security.access.company_voter:
    class:      Application\...\CompanyVoter
    public:     false
    tags:
       - { name: security.voter }
```

**Voter** *Application/.../CompanyVoter.php*

```php
#...
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes) 
{
    if ( !($this->supportsClass(get_class($object))) ) { # <- Problem here
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ( !$this->supportsAttribute($attribute) ) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }
    }

    $user = $token->getUser();
    if ( !($user instanceof UserInterface) ) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
    }

    if ( $user->getCompany() == $object->getCompany() ) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }

    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
}
#...
```

But every little call to the voter (except the first `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`) is giving an instance of `Application\...\CompanyVoter` as `$object` (2nd argument of `vote()`).

What can be the reason ?

Comment: hm how does the `supportsClass` function look? could you add it? having followed your answers here ... i strongly doubt you did something strange in there ... or does `get_class($object)` already return string `...\CompanyVoter` ?

Comment: `get_class($object)` always returns `Application\...\CompanyVoter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the object received is in fact always `NULL`.
`get_class(NULL)` returns the current class.

And after days of search, I finally found [where did that come from](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17530062/305189).

This is linked to the SonataAdmin RoleHandler `isGranted()` implementation. Yeah I was using my voters from a SonataAdmin bundle.