# SonataUser - Custom Voter with Role Security

Tags: security, symfony, symfony-security

I'm using SonataAdmin with `sonata.admin.security.handler.role` (so I don't use ACLs here).

I'm trying to restrict access to an object with a custom voter.

**service**

```yml
security.access.company_voter:
    class:      Application\...\Voter\CompanyVoter
    public:     false
    tags:
       - { name: security.voter }
```

**voter** *Application...\Voter\CompanyVoter.php*

```php
#...
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes) 
{
    get_class($object);
}
#...
```

But I'm always getting an instance of `Application\...\Voter\CompanyVoter` instead of the expected object to restrict.

What can be the reason ?

Are you telling me that Sonata does not pass the object to `isGranted()` when using the role security handler ?

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528191/symfony-voter-always-the-same-object-received ? :)

Comment: Quite related but this one is about SonataAdmin. The other is asked more globally.

Comment: so a voter object gets inserted basically into it's own vote method? ... that sounds pretty strange to me :D Where do you try to check your object and how exactly ? can you give some details about that?

Comment: Basically each time SonataAdmin fires `is_granted()`. Specifically I need to restrict the access to user edition.

Comment: This question might somehow be related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706428/passing-object-to-custom-voter ... the guy asking receives an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` instead of his object's FQCN. Did you manage to solve this issue meanwhile?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think his behavior is expected (receiving a Request instance for the first Voter call). Mine seems not because it always gives me the same CompanyVoter instance for each individual call. And no I still haven't been able to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of searching, I noticed that the object received is always `NULL` (`get_class(NULL)` returns the current class).

After days of seeking, It turns out that, as opposed to the ACL handler, [the default implementation](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Security/Handler/RoleSecurityHandler.php) of the Role handler [doesn't pass](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Security/Handler/RoleSecurityHandler.php#L48) the current object to `isGranted()`

I had then to extend it.

See a nice monologue in [my github issue](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1458) for more detail.