# Passing object to custom voter?

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I've been reading up about creating custom voters in Symfony 2.  According to [this page](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-users-menu-cms), it is possible to pass an object to the isGranted method of the securitycontext, which I have done in my own controller:

```
$page = new Page();

if ( ! $securityContext->isGranted('CONTENT_CREATE', $page)) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException('Fail');
}
```

It looks like the vote method should be accepting it, however, when I call get_class on the $object parameter, instead of getting my Page entity, I get:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{   
    print_r(get_class($object)); die();
    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
}
```

My voter is defined as a service in my services.yml file:

```
content_security.access.my_voter:
        class:      My\Bundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\MyVoter
        arguments:  ["@service_container"]
        public:     false
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hm i remember a similar question a few days ago ... trying to find it.

Comment: Found it ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530062/sonatauser-custom-voter-with-role-security ... Pierre received the voter class instead of the object's one with `get_class()`. this might be related. Did you try to dump the object ? Is it really the request or is `get_class` just returning a wrong FQCN.

Comment: Pierre posted a second question (almost the same) a few minutes later here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528191/symfony-voter-always-the-same-object-received

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every registered Voters is called when something calls isGranted.

The fact is that the framework itself (or a bundle f.e) calls isGranted on the request.

You have to use supportsClass, supportsAttribute, ... in order to check if the object is the one you're waiting for, and if not return a VoterInterface::ABSTAIN value.

Take a look at existing implementations (in the framework itself (like RoleVoter) or here: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/blob/develop/Security/Voter/IsOwnerVoter.php#L35-L45

Comment: +1 i didn't think of the voter being called for the request to the page aswell ... facepalm - this is the correct explanation, thx for enlightening me Florian :D